# Finding Group Name from Ldap GID

Tags: php, ldap

I have this issue, I'm have a user selected in LDAP through ldap search, giving only the attribute of gid.

```
    $ldapattributes = array("gidnumber");
    $ldapdn = "o=example";
    $ldapfilter = "(sn=".$ldapuname."*)";
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuname, $ldappass) or trigger_error('Could not bind to '.$ldaphost);
    $sr = ldap_search($ldapconn,$ldapbasedn,$ldapfilter,$ldapattributes);
    var_dump($sr);
    $entry = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $sr);
    var_dump($entry);
```

the result i get from the vardump is:

> 'gidnumber' => 
>           array
>             'count' => int 1
>             0 => string '1617' (length=4)

I know 1617 is the number that maps correctly to the group I want to, but, I'd like the text that's attributed to it elsewhere that says it's 'ConfSer'. I haven't been able to discover where this is, or how I could turn the gid into another filter to acquire the name and information of that particular group (so I can route it through a config file that spits out permissions).

EDIT: I get "CN=Ldaptst2 Majtst,O=example" in the results as well. But Neither of those are actually the group... just the full name.

Comment: Do you have NSS (Name Service Switch) on this system configured to use LDAP directory? Then you can use posix_getgrgid (and other posix_get* functions), otherwise you have to do another LDAP query to map gid number to group name. Sometimes (openldap etc.) a special overlay could be used to give you group name in single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct a search filter that will return all entries that have objectClass `posixGroup` and
the desired `gidNumber`, for example,
`(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(gidNumber=<insert-gid-number-here>))`. You must also supply a list
of attributes to return in the search result. Depending on which API used by your code using
this list of attributes might default to all user attributes. One of the attributes returned
will be the relative distinguished name of the group, and the search result itself will contain
the distinguished name of the group, which might be something like: `cn=group-of-users,dc=example,dc=com`.

From the command line, this search might be something like:

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p port -b dc=example,dc=com -s sub \
   '(&(objectClass=posixGroup)(gidNumber=<insert-gid-number-here>))' '*'
```

Comment: That was extremely helpful, but unfortunately, it didn't return anything like that in the CN, even after giving it the * attribute.

Comment: It was pretty much exactly what I ended up doing +/- realizing, oh, I'm using Domino.